# Self-type annotation, why to use self: => and not val?

Tags: scala

I have seen this code is pretty common:

```
trait A { this: B => ... }
trait A { self: B => ... }
```

But I'm wondering, why not to use this:

```
trait A { 
  val self: B = this

  //....
}
```

It this going to be an infinite recursion?

**UPDATE:**

Are these the same?

```
    trait A { self => ... }
    trait A { val self = this }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that in most useful cases your second version (using a field) simply won't compile.

```
trait A { self: B => ... }
```

What that snippet of code says is that any class that mixes in the `A` trait ***must*** also have type `B`. For example, if you are writing a trait that is only meant for use with your `Logger` class, then you can use `trait X { self: Logger => ... }` to communicate to the compiler that the `X` trait is only used as a mix-in for the `Logger` class.

In contrast, your alternative solution means something totally different:

```
trait A { 
  val self: B = this

  //....
}
```

This code will compile if and only if `B :> A` (`B` is a supertype of `A`). I can't think of any situation where this would be useful. Even if you have nested classes where an outer `this` might be hidden, you can still use the Java-like `OuterClassName.this` syntax to get the `this` reference for an enclosing class.

Comment: @Alex - The [self-type annotation syntax](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/explicitly-typed-self-references.html) creates an *alias* of `this` (i.e. the compiler will just replace `self` with the correct `this` reference), whereas you're actually creating an extra field when you declare `val self = this`.

Comment: I know that. I'm asking about the difference. Only overhead of one more field?

Comment: @Alex - Yeah, I think that would about sum it up—you'd just be adding a completely superfluous field. (Also note that Scala fields, unless declared `private[this]`, are actually more like Java field with getter/setter methods. That's why you an override a `def` with a `val`.)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is any significant difference
you could always replace

```
trait A { bla: B => }; trait AA extends A with B
```

with

```
 trait A { def bla: B }; trait AA extends A { val bla  = new B }
```

of course AA is not an instance of B in this case, but that looks like a benefit of not leaking an implementation detail

Comment: I think your answer is actually demonstrating that they _are_ different. The first implies an "is-a" relationship, while the second is a "has-a" relationship (i.e. inheritance vs composition). However, I'm confused how the composition example applies here since the OP is asking specifically about `this`.

Comment: is-a is implied by plain 'extends B', 'this: B' is better reflected by good old composition imo

Comment: Since the main use of the `this: B` syntax is for creating mix-in traits, which often override specific behaviors in `B`, I disagree that composition is a reasonable substitute.